# constraining angle in laser scan

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using "laser.bag" to publish the laser scan and then I am taking a temporary pointer to the subscribed laser scan and changing the angle_min and max to reduce the point cloud obtained by function "transformLaserScanToPointCloud()", but it does not work. When I visualize my published point cloud in RVIZ and compare it with the original point cloud (i.e. without any angle change) then only the direction of point cloud in RVIZ changes there is no any compression/reduction in point cloud.

Help me in getting the solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10117/constraining-angle-in-laser-scan/) by [ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/624/ravi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not sufficient to just change the metadata (i.e. angle_min/max) in the laserscan.  You need to modify the laserscan data itself to remove the points you wish to filter.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0